# Connecting Cassandra container using another container

Tags: python, docker, cassandra, containers

I am trying to connect to Cassandra container and insert data into the database by another container built by myself. I run Cassandra container by

```
docker pull Cassandra
docker run --name some-cassandra -p 9042:9042 -d cassandra:latest"
```

Here is the code I try to connect to Cassandra in my python program.

```
cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['127.0.0.1'],port=9042)
session = cluster.connect()
```

If I directly run the program on my Mac, it connects, but if I build it into container, it returns error:

```
raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

I build and run my container by

```
docker build --tag=restful .
docker run -p 4000:80 restful
```

I am new to docker, and I am wandering what is the right way to let these two container connect and communicate?

Comment: Notice you will lose all database data after the container crashes or is restarted - make sure to mount a persistent folder from the host (here: using `-v ${pwd}:/var/lib/cassandra`) to prevent data loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker containers are designed to be isolated from each other and the host machine.

Your Cassandra database is running on port `9042` inside the container as well as on the host machine. The argument `-p 9042:9042` tells Docker to bind the internal port 9042 with the host port 9042. This is why when you run your python script from the host (not inside any container) `127.0.0.1:9042` connects with your container.

When you put the same python script in a separate container, the IP address `127.0.0.1` no longer points to the host machine, but points to **current** container. Your python script can't connect to the Cassandra container simply because the two are isolated from each other.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Create a network with `docker create network test_net`. Then link both your containers to this network by adding the argument `--network=test_net` in the `docker run` command. Finally update the python script by replacing `127.0.0.1` with the name of the Cassandra container `some-cassandra`.
2. (Not recommended) Start your python script container bound to the host network by `--network=host` so that `127.0.0.1` now points to the host network.

Comment: Try the second method once. It will help debug whether there is a problem with the Cassandra container.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! It probably takes time to connect them to the network. It doesn't connect at the very first time, but after waiting for couple of seconds, it works.

Comment: I am also wandering how do I access Cassandra database after it is connecting to a  network. My previous command doesn't work after it is connected to a new network instead of host. `docker run --network=test_net -it --link some-cassandra:cassandra --rm cassandra `